# how to use the google-translate-api translation outside the method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-translation-api

I started using Cloud Google and implemented the translation API in my code but I can't use the response outside the callback.

```js
methods:{
        clicked(){
            const text = "Olá";
            const target = navigator.language;
            googleTranslate.translate(text, target, function(err, translation){
                console.log(translation.translatedText)
                //this.newText =  translation.translatedText;
            });
            //console.log(this.newText);
        },
    }
```

Show the error with or without the console.log. In the this.newText = translation.translatedText;

**Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'newText' of undefined"**

I would like to show the user the answer in the template. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the function keyword changes the 'this' context. You can either save 'this' outside of the function or use arrow functions.

Here's how you would use an arrow function

```
methods:{
    clicked(){
        const text = "Olá";
        const target = navigator.language;
        googleTranslate.translate(text, target, (err, translation) => {
            console.log(translation.translatedText)
            //this.newText =  translation.translatedText;
        });
        //console.log(this.newText);
    },
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Can you explain better the difference between the functions and the =>? I can't understand when I need to use one or the other

Comment: Arrow functions are considered easier to write because you don't have to write 'function' or 'return', but they're an ES6 feature, meaning that you would need to transpile your code if you're targeting IE11. The majority of the time you can use arrow functions with no problems. I found [this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/) was good at explaining them.